# how to call javascript function from client side on anchor click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

I have javascript function sample('textValue') and have to call at server side on anchor click. I tried below code

```
string text="xyz";
anchor.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:sample('"+text+"');
```

but the value of the text is not assigning correctly. Encoded string gets added. The result in view source looks like

```
javascript:sample(&#39;xyz&#39;)
```

But i need javascript:sample('xyz')

Comment: What server technology do you use? Disable escaping for that attribute value.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev  - its asp.net + c# on server side

Answer (score 0):

What server/backend language do you use? PHP? Do you use any framework (Zend, CakePHP...)?

On the JS side do something like this:

**Option 1**

```
<a href="/a_page" onclick="sample('text');">Test</a>
```

**Option 2**

```
<a href="/a_page" id="clicky-clack-link">Test</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('clicky-clack-link').onClick = function() {
        sample('test');
    };
</script>
```

*Note: Also check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com) if you haven't.*

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could just do this:

```
string text="xyz";
anchor.Attributes.Add("onclick", function(){ sample(text); } );
```

What does it do? Well, the `onclick` handler takes a function with no arguments, right? That is, *what* to do if somebody clicks the link. If you're coding this by hand in HTML, you can use the `javascript:a_statement_goes_here` to describe the code to run. I expect the browser will just create a function out of that. Since you're assigning this in JavaScript, you have to do that yourself (unless you write out to the document - that might work) and assign the function. But you don't have such a function yet - you have one `sample` that takes an argument - hence the anonymous function closing the `text` argument.

This is based on the assumption, that the above is actually client-side code. I'd be very surprised, if JS didn't allow you to assign a function to an attribute. In fact, I think the problem you are running into, is JavaScript trying to be very smart and make sure assigning a string, will stay a string - that is why your `'` got encoded.

Have a go, tell me how it went. Ta!

Comment: That can't possibly work because `string` is not valid JS and `function () {}` is not valid C#

Comment: ah, well spotted. ok, I was assuming this was JS client side code. you know what they say about assumption...